# I was trying to Validate XMl files aginst xsd using python

Tags: python, xml, validation, xsd, lxml

here is my xml file :

```xml
\<Orderdetails\>
\<Customer id="011"\>
\<cname\>Mark Lewis\</cname\>
\<destination Country="Australia" Delivdate=" 6 days"\>Free Delivery\</destination\>
\<eid\>MarkLew@hotmail.com\</eid\>
\</Customer\>
\<Customer id="022"\>
\<fname from="jersey"\>Loafther cris\</fname\>
\<destination Country="USA" Delivdate=" 11 days"\>Shipping Charges\</destination\>
\<eid\>Loafther@email.com\</eid\>
\</Customer\>
\<Customer id="033"\>
\<cname\>Amal Raj\</cname\>
\<destination Country="Thailand" Delivdate=" 6 days"\>Shipping Charges\</destination\>
\<email\>Anamljjk@ymail.com\</email\>
\</Customer\>
\</Orderdetails\>
```

Here is my XSD file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:element name="Orderdetails">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element maxOccurs="unbounded" name="Customer">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="fname">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute name="from" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="cname" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="destination">
<xs:complexType>
<xs:simpleContent>
<xs:extension base="xs:string">
<xs:attribute name="Country" type="xs:string" use="required" />
<xs:attribute name="Delivdate" type="xs:string" use="required" />
</xs:extension>
</xs:simpleContent>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="email" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="eid" type="xs:string" />
</xs:sequence>
<xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:unsignedByte" use="required" />
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Error:

Getting the below error:

```
SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape
```

the error I'm getting during run

Code:
I am trying to validate using the code written below:

```
from lxml import etree
from validator import validate

def validate(xml_path: str, xsd_path: str) -> bool:

    xmlschema_doc = etree.parse(xsd_path)
    xmlschema = etree.XMLSchema(xmlschema_doc)
    xml_doc = etree.parse(xml_path)
    result = xmlschema.validate(xml_doc)

    return result
    
    
xml_path="C:\Users\nisha\Downloads\xmlfile\demo.xml"
xsd_path="C:\Users\nisha\Downloads\xsdfile\demo.xsd"

value=validate(xml_path,xsd_path)
print(value)
```

With the double slashes in path it got further , but getting the following error now :

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'validator'
```

Comment: Are all those backslashes actually present in your XML, or are they spurious?

Comment: Remove the `from validator import validate` line. The validator library is not used for XSD validation: https://pypi.org/project/validator.

Comment: Can you use a Hex editor and tell as what the first 3 bytes are in the file?